# Is there any function in Python which returns the relative frequency of a specified range of a sample?

Tags: python

Is it possible to calculate the relative frequency of range [88-102] occurring in a array in Python?
For example:

[ 75,85,88,90,92,94,96,98,99,100,100,102,103,104,105,107,110,114,115,124] # answer: 10/20=0.50

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the list and try to see in the number is withing your given range

```
a = [75,85,88,90,92,94,96,98,99,100,100,102,103,104,105,107,110,114,115,124]
f = 0
for x in a:
    if x >= 88 and x <= 102:
        f += 1

print(f/len(a))
```

One liner

```
res = sum([1 if 88<=i<=102 else 0 for i in list])
```

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your answer. Though i was mostly eager for a pre-defined function from library etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`numpy.histogram()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram), although this method is slower.

```
import numpy as np

data = [75, 85, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 99, 100, 100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 107, 110, 114, 115, 124]

frequency = np.histogram(data, range=(88, 102))[0].size / len(data)
print(frequency)  # 0.5
```

---

- `np.histogram()[0]` will return the values of the histogram (`[1 1 1 0 1 1 0 2 2 1]`). You can then use `size` to get the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is sorted (as your example seems to suggest) you can use the following function:

```
def freq(arr, min_n, max_n):
    return (
        len(arr) -
        next((j for j in range(len(arr)) if arr[j] >= min_n), len(arr)) -
        next((j for j in range(len(arr)) if arr[len(arr) - j - 1] <= max_n), len(arr))
    ) / len(arr)
```

In the worst case (freq=0) the complexity is O(2n). In the best case (freq=1) the complexity is O(1).